# python3 - storing username & hashed password in a .csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv

so before i start AS-level computer science next year, i have a little practice task to do over the summer.

Its a game that requires a log in with username and password, and then requires to store the users scores.

Originally i was just going to have a .txt file named after each user, with the first line being a plaintext password, which the program reads during login. to save the score i was going to append the raw score onto a new line at the end of the document.

Now i think about it, im wondering if it would be better and tidier to have a .csv file and save all the usernames of each user in the first column, then a salted and hashed password on the second column, relating to the user by being in the same row (mainly because i think thats interesting and would like to learn it, rather that it being necessary for my program) then having the next rows each score taken.

I don't really know how i would go about checking the first column to find if there is a username the same as the user is trying to input, then how i would compare the password inputted to the password in same row but one column along

Any advice will be greatly appreciated, however in the meantime i will try and figure it out (afterall you should "*Code to Learn, not Learn to Code*")
i will post back if i get anywhere

thanks in advance for any help :)
Alex

Comment: How about a database? You could use the built-in [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). (BTW this seems like a tool/off-site resource recommendation, which is off topic.)

Comment: i will definitely have a look into it, however last time i tried to use SQL i massively over complicated things for myself :P

Comment: you could try something like https://github.com/jaraco/keyring for secure password storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think csv is the right format to store passwords in Python. How about using json?

I've written some example which wraps around some `dict`, and stores it's content into a json-file:

```
import codecs
import crypt
import hmac
import json
import os


class Secret:
    def __init__(self, filename='passwords.json'):
        self.filename = filename
        self.content = self.read_file()

    def read_file(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.filename):
            with codecs.open(self.filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as rf:
                return json.loads(rf.read())

        # create defaults if file does not exist
        return dict(
            salt=crypt.mksalt(),
            users=dict()
        )

    def write_file(self):
        with codecs.open(self.filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as wf:
            return wf.write(json.dumps(self.content, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

    def set_user_password(self, name, password):
        self.content['users'][name] = crypt.crypt(name, password)
        self.write_file()

    def check_user_password(self, name, password):
        if name in self.content['users']:
            hashed = self.content['users'][name]
            if hmac.compare_digest(hashed, crypt.crypt(name, password)):
                return True
        return False
```

**Please note**:

This Example is blindly based on the documentation of the [crypt-module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html) - I have no clue if this in any way secure (probably not).
Further: I don't know if it's good to store the salt alongside the passwords.

You can use it like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    secret = Secret(filename='passwords.json')
    secret.set_user_password('demo_user', 'lolcat')

    for user, password in [
            ('demo_user', 'lolcat'),
            ('demo_user', 'wrong_pass'),
            ('wrong_user', 'wrong_pass'),
    ]:
        print(
            'user:', user, 'password:', password,
            '\n-->', secret.check_user_password(user, password)
        )
```

It creates a json-File like this:

```
{
    "salt": "rT",
    "users": {
        "demo_user": "lo1JY.PCooh4."
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for the input, i chose to just use a txt file in the end, as this was far easier to do. As it was only a practice piece over summer, the password storage didnt need to be secure, but i found hashing the password interesting.  Here is the final game if you are interested (its quite clunky but it works, i'm sure i'll improve it over the next few weeks) : [code](http://pastebin.com/UPnMyuWP)